# Where is MobyLCPSolver?

Tags: drake

Where is MobyLCPSolver?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MobyLCPSolver' from 'pydrake.all' (/home/docker/drake/drake-build/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/all.py)
```

I have the latest Drake and cannot import it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

As of pydrake v1.12.0, the `MobyLcp` C++ API is not bound in Python.

However, if you feed an LCP into `Solve()` then Drake can choose Moby to solve it.  You can take advantage of this to create an instance of `MobyLCP`:

```py
import numpy as np

from pydrake.all import (
    ChooseBestSolver,
    MakeSolver,
    MathematicalProgram,
)

prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2)
prog.AddLinearComplementarityConstraint(np.eye(2), np.array([1, 2]), x)
moby_id = ChooseBestSolver(prog)
moby = MakeSolver(moby_id)
print(moby.SolverName())

# The output is: "Moby LCP".
# The C++ type of the `moby` object is drake::solvers::MobyLCP.
```

That only allows for calling Moby via the MathematicalProgram interface, however.  To call any `MobyLCP`-specific C++ functions like `SolveLcpFastRegularized`, those would need to be added to the bindings code specifically before they could be used.

You can file a feature request on the Drake GitHub page when you need access to C++ classes or functions that aren't bound into Python yet, or even better you can open a pull request with the bindings that you need.